# Prevent twitter4j from printing output when displaying a Twitter stream

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

How would I go about getting the live Twitter feed (or whatever part of it Twitter provides, 1% from what I hear) using twitter4j without having twitter4j print everything to the console output? Although I initially thought that this would mean that one had to turn off logging, trying to turn off logging has not helped. I would prefer an "in-code" solution to one which would require me to pass a VM Argument.

An SSCCE for the problem I'm facing would be:

```
import twitter4j.*;

public class StreamTweets {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                // do whatever I want here
            }
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}
            public void onException(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {}
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning arg0) {}
        };

        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory().getInstance();
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.sample();
    }
}
```

NB: Whatever I require to be done, which would entail storing everything into a database, I will be doing in the onStatus() method of the StatusListener(). Not sure that this is very relevant, but thought I'd put it out there just in case.

Comment: So just to confirm: after running with the vm arg `-Dtwitter4j.loggerFactory=twitter4j.NullLoggerFactory` you are still seeing some console output? Would it be possible to add an example of the output to the question please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are providing Twitter credentials through twitter4j.properties as mentioned [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html), then change the first line of twitter4j.properties file to

```
debug=false
```

This will stop printing to console on receiving Twitter Stream!

Comment: This worked. Remember to refresh the project (Right click on the project name -> Refresh) after you set debug to 'false', so that the content of 'twitter4j.properties' is reloaded.

Comment: Does it have to be using `twitter4j.properties` to get it to work? I'm using `ConfigurationBuilder` and it did not work. Neither did adding the properties file...

Comment: @hello_its_me I had the same problem even after usign the twitter4j.properties file. What solved it for me was configuring logging properly. I used logback for that. My guess is that if logging is not configured the twitter stream just defaults to using the stdoutput for everything it does.